# PC crashes due to GPU or GPU drivers (Nvidia)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have a notebook (Acer Aspire E1-772G) with the following Hardware (all stock items, no modifications):

CPU: Intel i5-4200M 2.5GHz

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4600 + Nvidia GeForce 820M

The only modification I made was to add an additional mSata SSD (more than a year ago).

With this setup it now worked for some years without problems (previously with Windows 8 Pro, upgraded to Windows 10 last year).
Some days ago my notebook crashed and I got the following error while booting: Blue Screen with sad smiley :(  saying:

"System_Thread_Exception_Not_Handled (nvlddmkm.sys)"

The notebook failed restarting several times and I had to start in safe mode. After some research I found out that it had something to do with the Nvidia drivers. So I uninstalled them and I could boot in normal mode, thinking I had fixed the issue.

The problem now is that as soon as I have installed the Nvidia drivers again, the system crashes directly. This even happens when windows installs the drivers by itself (as soon as I connect to the internet without disabling the undetected graphics card in the device manager, the system will crash immediately). Disabling the undetected graphics card in the device manager however only works until the next reboot since Windows does not seem to store the disabling information for undetected hardware.

I can however install the drivers in safe mode and then deactivate the GPU in the device manager. This allows me to boot in normal mode without problems but obviously does not let me use the GPU.

Any idea how I can fix this? Is my Nvidia gpu broken?

EDIT 1 29/05/2016: 
I checked the [Acer website](http://www.acer.com/ac/de/DE/content/drivers) for drivers but there is no nvidia driver enlisted for Windows 10.

EDIT 2 29/05/2016: 
I now tried to install the Nvidia drivers from the acer website provided for Windows 8 64bit. This seems to work (driver version 327.41). But as soon as I installed the update downloaded by Nvidia Experience (driver version 386.22) the system crashed again.

Is there a possibility to receive newer versions <strike>or should I just let it be on the version that seems to work now</strike>  ?

EDIT 3 29/05/2016: 
It also crashes when Windows does an automatic driver update with the Windows 8 driver version from Acer.

Comment: try downloading the drivers from Acer, specifically for your notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to answer my post. After some time (and the major Windows 10 update (Redstone?)) everything seems to work fine again. I could enable my GPU again and update the drive to the newest version without crashing.

It seems that this specific problems was fixed with the Windows update. At least it is the only explanation I have.